# Updating serial no. in a table on events of data insert and data delete

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Let’s consider I have table with three columns; Serial Id, Employee Name and Employee Salary. Whenever data will be inserted into this table, the column Serial Id will have incremented value like 1,2,3,4 and so on.  Now the next part is whenever data will be deleted, the entire Serial Id values will get adjusted. Deletion of a row can happen at the starting row, last row or anywhere within the table. How do we get this done through PL/SQL.

Comment: what do u mean by "the entire Serial Id values will get adjusted."?. Please elaborate with sample data.

Comment: I would suggest you to add one additional column, which will have a real ID value, generated from a sequence (this is good for the indexes you might have on that column, or PK constraints). Then, either in the procedure that inserts records in the table, or in a Trigger (a before insert, update, delete trigger), you can adjust whatever column the way you like it and then Oracle will just commit it (if you have this in the code of course).

Comment: @KaushikNayak."The entire Serial Id values will get adjusted" means suppose there are 10 rows in the table and the Serial Id is created from 1 to 10.Now if the last row gets deleted (which is the easier part) Serial Id will exist from 1 to 9.However if the first row gets deleted then the second row will have Serial Id =1, 3rd row will have Serial Id = 2 and so on. Again suppose if the 5th row is deleted then the first 4 rows will remain unchanged but 6th row will have Serial Id = 5, 7th row will have Serial Id = 6 and so on. This event has to happen automatically whenever there is a deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This can be accomplished using the following steps, but note that you cannot delete from the table directly. Instead , you can delete from a view with the same structure and update the parent table using an Instead of Trigger. Also, Since you are deleting ID from the employee table, there should be at least one other key to uniquely identify the employee. Considering all these precursors, Here are the steps.

create a `UNIQUE KEY` ON `employee_name`. This step is not mandatory if you can ensure that employee_name is always unique across the table. But there is no way to identify the employee record if we don't.

```
ALTER TABLE emp ADD CONSTRAINT emp_uk UNIQUE(employee_name);
```

Next Create a View which has the same definition of the `emp` table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emp_view AS
SELECT * FROM EMP;
```

Create an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` for the row-wise delete operations 
on the view  `emp_view`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigg_emp_v INSTEAD OF
  DELETE ON emp_view FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE
  FROM EMP
  WHERE emp_id = :OLD.emp_id ;
  MERGE INTO EMP e USING
  (SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY emp_id) emp_id,
    employee_name,
    salary
  FROM
    ( SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id != :OLD.emp_id
    )
  ) v ON ( e.employee_name = v.employee_name )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET e.emp_id = v.emp_id;
END;
/
```

Here the select query is fetching the recalculated `emp_id` using the `RANK()` function and the `merge` statement is updating the emp table.

Test for `ID = 5`

```
Before Deletion

    SELECT * FROM EMP;

    EMP_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME                                SALARY
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
         1 EMPLOYEE_1                                     1001
         2 EMPLOYEE_2                                     1002
         3 EMPLOYEE_3                                     1003
         4 EMPLOYEE_4                                     1004
         5 EMPLOYEE_5                                     1005
         6 EMPLOYEE_6                                     1006
         7 EMPLOYEE_7                                     1007
         8 EMPLOYEE_8                                     1008
         9 EMPLOYEE_9                                     1009
        10 EMPLOYEE_10                                    1010
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Delete operation

```
DELETE FROM EMP_VIEW where emp_id = 5;
```

After Deletion,Output is something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP;
    EMP_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME                                SALARY
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
         1 EMPLOYEE_1                                     1001
         2 EMPLOYEE_2                                     1002
         3 EMPLOYEE_3                                     1003
         4 EMPLOYEE_4                                     1004
         5 EMPLOYEE_6                                     1006
         6 EMPLOYEE_7                                     1007
         7 EMPLOYEE_8                                     1008
         8 EMPLOYEE_9                                     1009
         9 EMPLOYEE_10                                    1010
```

Let me know Your Feedback.